# How do you deal with referencing binary files inside "CSS in JS" solutions like JSS and Aphrodite?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, inline-styles

Not sure how to handle referencing binary files in "CSS in JS" solutions.  Webpack does this by default by referencing everything as absolute.  So I'm wondering if there's a solution outside of Webpack?

Answer (score 0):

> solution outside of Webpack?

Did you mean stand along library?

You can try this one: [cssobj](https://github.com/cssobj/cssobj)

Comment: more like updating the static reference (jpg|gif|png|svg) with absolute url.  I think its more of a build tool's job by now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JS constant with an absolute path and use it as a prefix for your path to an image and co.